# Google NID cookie is set despite consent

Tags: google-analytics

Question is, is there a way to **absolutely** block **NID cookie** prior to user has given any consent or denied it? Website [in question](https://liedaga.liepaja.edu.lv/).

[image]

I'm using ComplianZ plugin in Wordpress. Have used CookieYes plugin as well. Both allow it, tried https://www.consentmanager.net/. They all MISS this cookie. Despite Google documentation states it is a "preference" type cookie, many cookie scanners, including cookiebot.com, position this cookie as "marketing", i.e. ads. A report by an external data protection officer, states I need to get rid of it. There simply should not be any NID or CONSENT cookie from google.com.

PS. I'm currently jumping in between plugin developer forums / Google Site kit / Google documentation / cookie scanners and DPO for 2 weeks now. I'm about to uninstall Google Site Kit and delete Google analytics from the website, however useful and valuable these tools may be. The DPO states there is no middle ground in regards to GDPR and Google cookies, despite IP anonymization is set on the website. Same applies to embedded  Google docs from docs.google.com - despite being initially blocked by domain, these still manage to place their cookies. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

**That cookie is not dependent from your website**. Google installs it when you go to the Google site or use its services such as access to the Google account.

If you try to open your website directly as a *Guest* you will see that there is no NID cookie (certainly not before accepting cookies or after rejecting them).

It does not depend on Google Analytics (which installs first-party cookies), nor on anonymizeIp (which has a completely different purpose) or anything else.

It just doesn't depend on you or your website.

Comment: After I wrote the initial post, I have figured out the answer. The issue was not with Google Analytics or ComplianZ plugin. It was with the embedded Google docs. Once I removed the <iframe> tag NID was gone. Had to hyperlink, instead of <iframe>. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 1):

My issue was docs.google.com pulling NID cookie from google.com domain. By removing embedded  Google documents, the NID is gone.

Answer (score 0):

This is likely caused by a browser extension you have installed. If you view the website in Incognito Mode (and so disabling all extensions) you will likely see that it does not appear anymore.